# Contact form 7 file field related query

Tags: wordpress

We have required conditional file field that depends on another dropdown field. If dropdown field value YES then file field will show and added required option but if dropdown value NO then file field not show and remove the required option.

We have done the hide show logic in file field but not able to do required option on off. Can anyone please suggest how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Without the exact website link, it is difficult to explain perfectly. However, from what I understand what you need to do here is to implement a custom validation.

You can refer this [link](http://vasashreya.blogspot.in/2016/12/contact-form-7-custom-validation-hook.html) to understand how to implement custom validation.

Basic flow of code:
1. Give ID to the drop down so that you can bind an onchange event with it
2. Bind an onchange event that hide/show the file field
3. Create custom required validation which checks your drop down value and decides whether the other field is required or not

This should do your job... Feel free to ask other questions and post your website uRL and code to get a better answer.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. For file input field can i use add_filter( 'wpcf7_validate_file*', 'custom_file_validation_filter', 20, 2 ); Please suggest

Comment: wpfc7_validate_<control_type> is how you define your filter. So for text field, it will be wpfc7_validate_text* and for file wpfc7_validate_file*

Comment: So if user select no from dropdown then with above filter can i remove required option for file field?